# Float right, Left justify items in list

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to create a navigation with item names on the left and a status on the right. I would like to keep both of these items in the same list, but my problem is that I can not float the status text right and still left justify.

Here is what I am trying to create

[image: List Design]

Here is my current HTML

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="col-xs-4">
  <p class="list-title">Blueprint</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Executive Summary <span>Dean Approved</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mission, Vision, Values <span>In Progress</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Unit Goal Management <span>In Progress</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <p class="list-title">Outcomes</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Goal Outcomes <span>Dean Approved</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Academic Intivates <span>Dean Approved</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Faculty Information <span>In Progress</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teaching <span>Dean Approved</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Student Recruiting &amp; Retention <span>Pending Dean Approval</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Faculty Award Nomination <span>Pending Dean Approval</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Faculty Awards <span>In Progress</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Community Engagement <span>Dean Rejected</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Collaborations <span>In Progress</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Campus Climate &amp; Inclusion <span>Not started</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Concluding Remarks <span>Not started</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I float the span right, but I have no way to left justify it after that. I've tried having two lists, one with the names and one with status. This works until I try to add hover or active states.

I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Add a tag (e.g. `<span>`) to the title so that you'd be able to manipulate it as well. From there, I'm pretty sure you know what to do. Also, when asking questions, please read the guidelines first. The title almost makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text in the spans are technically left justified, even after floating right, its just that the width of the spans is only as wide as the text. So left, right, center justified all look the same. Set a minimum width on the spans and you'll be able to control the text-alignment. Something like:

```
ul > li > a > span {
    float: right;
    min-width: 200px;
    /* text-align: left */ /* it's left by default */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a solution to your floating issue, but why can't you just use display: inline-block on the span elements?

So break up the list of the code from:

```
    <li><a href="#">Executive Summary <span>Dean Approved</span></a></li>
```

to

```
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Executive Summary</span> <span class="status">Dean Approved</span></a></li>
```

And then set up the two spans as display: inline-block and vertical-align: middle.

And then for the .status span, you can set a text-align: right to make it right justified.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, and it didn't seem to work. The status span is still against the title span.